# Getting 'Invalid column name ...' even after making the property data attribute 'NotMapped'

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlexception

I'm not sure why, but when trying to fetch a 'Product'

```
return context.Products.SingleOrDefault(m => m.Id == id);
```

I'm getting a Sql Exception that says ''Invalid column name 'DefendantId1'.'

Not sure why it has a 1 after the name and not sure why I'm getting this error after I made the property not mapped

In my Property object I have

```
public class Product
{
    // other props here
    [NotMapped]
    public int DefendantId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: That column is probably the result of a foreign key relationship with another object.

Comment: so, should I check the db? There isn't anything in the modelbuilder

Comment: try `return context.Products.Where(m => m.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: just tried that and received the same error.

Comment: No, check the models in your project.  EF has a misconfigured foreign key relationship with another object.

Comment: oh, right, I forgot about the mapping in the other object. Removing it worked! Thanks